# Base way to store the Dictionary values

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, dictionary

I have a scenario where i need to store the values.I have a app where i want to save values.
I am working on Windows 8 Phone application.

It has multiple topics and each topic will have 3 different values to store.

Like

```
1) IT  -> employees -25
       -> resources -25
       -> buildings -32

2) College -> students -33
           -> buildings -4
           -> faculty -35
```

and so on...

Now i have these values in `Dictionary<string,string>` Every time when i add these values to dictionary i need to store these values to retrive it back and display.

These values should be present until the app is uninstalled from device, and also if i want to clear the saved results i should be able to do that as well.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Use of Sqlite is much better idea.

Comment: see this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/save-and-read-data-from-isolated-storage-in-window-phone-7/

Comment: i am trying to do similar to that

Comment: Go for this link http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671

Comment: @Jaihind i dont want to use Sqlite, i would lkike to save it in some txt file and retrive it

Comment: Data manipulation is more complicated in txt or xml file compare to sqlite. why you don't want to go with sqlite.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49751/discussion-between-user2056563-and-jaihind)

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to store this in a dataset? There is no limit to the amount of tables / columns / rows of information you have and you can ise LINQ to query the data very fast!

Here is an example :) Hope this helps!

```
using System;
using System.Data;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    // Create two DataTable instances.
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("patients");
    table1.Columns.Add("name");
    table1.Columns.Add("id");
    table1.Rows.Add("sam", 1);
    table1.Rows.Add("mark", 2);

    DataTable table2 = new DataTable("medications");
    table2.Columns.Add("id");
    table2.Columns.Add("medication");
    table2.Rows.Add(1, "atenolol");
    table2.Rows.Add(2, "amoxicillin");

    // Create a DataSet and put both tables in it.
        DataSet set = new DataSet("office");
    set.Tables.Add(table1);
    set.Tables.Add(table2);

    // Visualize DataSet.
    Console.WriteLine(set.GetXml());
    }
}
```

Comment: see this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/save-and-read-data-from-isolated-storage-in-window-phone-7/